# Wordpress NextGEN loop through images from specific album

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I would like to loop through the images of a specific album in NextGen.

I want to use a NextGen album to create a banner slideshow in the themes header.php. Something like:

```
loop through images in album = x:
$src = src of image
$title = title of image
echo $src and $title
```

How to do this?

**Found a solution:**

```
global $nggdb;
$gallery = $nggdb->get_gallery(8, 'sortorder', 'ASC', true, 0, 0);
foreach($gallery as $image) {
    echo $image->imageURL;
    echo $image->alttext;
    echo $image->description;
 }
```

All other $image attributes can be printed aswell

Comment: Please, add the solution as an Answer, so this Question don't hangs in the "Unanswered" category.

Comment: I have been searching for some decent online docs for nextGen. I've run the source through doxygen and that helps but have found no working examples. Does anyone have a link?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering the question with *zvinxs* solution:

```
global $nggdb;
$gallery = $nggdb->get_gallery(8, 'sortorder', 'ASC', true, 0, 0);
foreach($gallery as $image) {
    echo $image->imageURL;
    echo $image->alttext;
    echo $image->description;
 }
```

Comment: This loops through a gallery, not an album

Comment: The exactly loop through gallery. Awesome!

Comment: Thanks for the above solution guys... is there any other way where we can use gallery title instead of gallery id to pull all the image links?